# Cannot connect to SQL Server with Windows authentication from C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclient

I want to connect to SQL Server 2016 using Windows authentication.

I am using C# with this connection string

```
Server=192.168.1.12,14331;Database=master;Integrated Security=true;Timeout=30
```

or

```
Server=serversql\newinstance;Database=master;Integrated Security=true;Timeout=30
```

The error is a timeout connection.

When using connection with SQL Server authentication like this:

```
Server=192.168.1.12,14331;Database=master;User Id=***;Password=****;Timeout=30
```

everything is ok.

Source code C#

```cs
var constr = "<connection string>";

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
    var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    command.CommandText = "SELECT 1";
    command.CommandTimeout = 0;

    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

But when I am using SQL Server Management Studio to check connection to the SQL Server instance with Windows authentication, it is ok. Using alias or Ip address does not help the error.

I don't understand why I get this error ...

Help me please!  Thanks you everyone!

**UPDATE:**
If I use connection 1 with IP and port, there is an error:

> Login failed. The login is from an untrusted domain and cannot be used
> with Windows

**UPDATE:**
Instance SQL installed on other PC the same network LAN with My PC.
I'm checked Log Viewer on PC install instance SQL but no record log.

Comment: I'm sorry. I edited question. Could you help me!

Comment: @MrMy Gserg is saying that the 2 connection strings are trying to connect to 2 completely instances, and on 2 different hosts. Just because you can connect to one instance doesn't mean you can connect to another when they could be (or likely to be) configured differently.

Comment: @GSerg i'm sorry. i edited question. two host is same with ip 192.168.1.12 and port 14331 and alias is serversql\newinstance

Comment: Can you see the connection attempt (using windows authentication) in the SQL Server's log? if so, what details are logged?

Comment: @Larnu I checked log but no log write on Event Viewer.

Comment: Re your update: There are quite a lot of resources about this error already - [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=The+login+is+from+an+untrusted+domain+and+cannot+be+used+with+Windows). Have you looked at anything so far?

Comment: For integrated Security to work the User needs an account on both local a remote machines and the account (or group) need read/write access to the database.  I would try using SQL Server Management Studio from remote machine and make sure the login window is set to Windows Credentials.  SSMS will give better error diagnostics on what is causing issue.

Comment: @jdweng I'm using SSMS connect is  successful, but i using C# is error?.

Comment: @ADyson I was checked list. but my problem is i using SSMS is connect success but using C# is error?.

Comment: Then I would suggest there is a difference in the environments - maybe the connection to SSMS uses a subtly different set of connection details, and/or the C# code maybe runs under a different username, and/or from a different machine, perhaps? You'd need to describe the architecture more clearly

Comment: @ADyson i'm using simple winform application to run c# code, and i debug with current user window. This user to open SSMS to connect instace sql is success

Comment: With SSMS are you try a query?  You may be able to connect but do not have permissions to read database.   Are you an Admin?  If you are running in VS you do not have Admin privileges unless you create a VS shortcut and then start VS by right click shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Answer (score -2):

I'm not sure it works for you, but you can try it:

```
SqlConnection cnn;
public connect(){
    string strConnect = @"Data Source=192.168.1.12,14331;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial Catalog=master;User ID=****;Password=*****";
    cnn = new SqlConnection(strConnect);
    try
    {
        cnn.Open();
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
        // connect failed
    }
}
public void ExeQuery(string query){
    // query="select * from tblA"
    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(query,cnn);
    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    sql.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I want to use window authentication, not sql user. I'm using sql user is success but using window authentication is error in spite of using Sql Management Studio is connect successful